# Refresh time slider UI

Tags: python, animation, interface

When you run the following code from the script editor when having a cube selected:

```
import bpy

for x in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    x.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'location', index = 1)

#Updates the Transform UI panel when run as an addon
for region in bpy.context.area.regions:
    if region.type == 'UI':
        region.tag_redraw()
```

You set a keyframe on the Y axis and the UI panel would be refreshed when the script is an addon, but the dopesheet does not refresh(see attached screenshot).
[image]

How do I safely refresh the dopesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to include the areas while looping to the regions. Note the region.type in dopesheet is Window.

```
import bpy

for x in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    x.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'location', index = 1)

#Updates all animation related UI
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'UI':
                region.tag_redraw()
    elif area.type == 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                region.tag_redraw()
            if region.type == 'CHANNELS':
                region.tag_redraw()
    elif area.type == 'GRAPH_EDITOR':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                region.tag_redraw()
            if region.type == 'CHANNELS':
                region.tag_redraw()
    elif area.type == 'NLA_EDITOR':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                region.tag_redraw()
            if region.type == 'CHANNELS':
                region.tag_redraw()
    elif area.type == 'OUTLINER':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                region.tag_redraw()
    elif area.type == 'PROPERTIES':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                region.tag_redraw()
```